# Can I disable the new PS3 boot warning?

Tags: ps3

I got a system update and now my PS3 helpfully reminds me to consult the manual when it boots.  Is there an option somewhere to turn that back off?

Edit:  In my impatience I had not noticed that the warning goes away automatically even if you don't hit <kbd>X</kbd> so this warning is not as annoying as I originally thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think there's a way to turn it off. It came with the latest PS3 update, 4.0, which supports the PS Vita.

Answer (score 0):

On retail units you cannot deactivate it and it's not going to be deactivatable with any firmware update.